# Dynamically adding multiple fragments to a single layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-relativelayout

It is possible to add multiple fragments dynamically, i have an requirements of multiple pages but that is not fixed it may be 4 or 6, so it is possible to add fragment dynamically, if yes then how to add.

Answer (score 1):

You can use ViewPager and Tabs somethings like a browser

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible, pass your Model object as an `argument` to a fragment and load the same fragment with new Data.

For an Example

```
 public class MyFragment extends Fragment{

    public static MyFragment getInstance(Bundle bundle){
        MyFragment myFragment = new MyFragment();
        myFragment.setArguments(bundle);
        return myFragment;
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
        // inflate layout and Get argument here and set the data to UI
    }
}
```

On every `Button` click manage the index of the data object and pass the clicked index data to the fragment as a `Bundle`